# C++ pointer to pointer of array

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

how to pass array to this function ?

this is the function :

```
void fire(const uint8_t *const s[])
{
cout<<*s<<endl;
}
```

and I want to pass this array to that :

```
unsigned char X[10] = {255,255,255,255};
```

it is done by this and it works

```
unsigned char X[5] = {255,255,255,255};
unsigned char *pointertoX ;
pointertoX = X;
fire(&pointertoX);
```

why I need *pointertoX ?
is there any other way for do this ?

whole code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void fire(const uint8_t *const s[])
{
cout<<*s<<endl;
}


int main() {


unsigned char X[10] = {255,255,255,255};
unsigned char *pointertoX ;
pointertoX = X;
fire(&pointertoX);


    return 0;
}
```

note : I'm trying to pass bitmap to ffmpeg "sws_scale" ..

https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__libsws.html#gae531c9754c9205d90ad6800015046d74

Comment: FYI, there is no overload of `operator<<` that prints an entire array.  You need to iterate through an array to print each element.  In other words, in your code, `cout << X << "\n";` is not valid because there is no functionality for outputting the X array; you need to iterate through the `X` array to print it.  There is an exception and that is arrays of `char`, which are intended to be C-Style arrays.  When you `cout` a character array, the `cout` is expecting to see a nul terminating character.  The `cout` will print all locations of the array and beyond until nul terminator is found.

Comment: IMHO, creating a `struct` containing the pixel elements would easier to handle (pass around, print, and modify) rather than a 4 slot array, e.g. `struct Pixel {uint8_t red, blue, green, alpha; };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is the function :
>
> ```
> void fire(const uint8_t *const s[])
> ```

That function accepts a pointer to a `const` pointer to a `const uint8_t`.

> and I want to pass this array to that :
>
> ```
>  unsigned char X[10] = {255,255,255,255};
> ```

You cannot.

In order to pass an array into a function that accepts a pointer, the function would have to accept a pointer to element type of that array (after other implicit conversions such as pointer from to non-const into pointer to const). The element of that array is `unsigned char`, while the function accepts a pointer to a `const` pointer to a `const uint8_t`.

> why I need *pointertoX ?

Because the function accepts a pointer to a `const` pointer to a `const uint8_t`, and `&pointertoX` is a pointer to a pointer to an `unsigned char`. Given that `uint8_t` is an alias of `unsigned char`, `&pointertoX` is implicitly convertible to the function parameter.

---

> note : I'm trying to pass bitmap to ffmpeg "sws_scale" ..

Read the documentation carefully:

> > srcSlice    the array containing the **pointers** to the planes of the source slice
> >
> > dst the array containing the **pointers** to the planes of the destination image

You're trying to pass an array of characters into a function that expects an array of pointers.

---

P.S. The behaviour of the program is undefined because `*s` does not point to a null terminated string, but you insert it into a character stream which has such requirement.